# Why all the script in my git hooks (pre-commit, post-commit, pre-receive, pre-push etc) do not run?

Tags: bash, git, githooks, git-server

Why all the script in my git hooks (pre-commit, post-commit, pre-receive, pre-push etc) do not run?

Note:
this question is not a duplicate;

I have try the answer to each of the other questions but none of them work.

I did `chmod +x`, added the path to hook. rename script, neither of them solve my issue.

> Inside my git

`branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs`

> Inside hooks:

```
applypatch-msg.sample  fsmonitor-watchman.sample  post-update.sample     pre-commit         prepare-commit-msg.sample  pre-rebase.sample  update.sample
commit-msg             post-merge.sh              pre-applypatch.sample  pre-commit.sample  pre-push                   pre-receive
```

I run them manually and they are all working fine.:

```
$ bash pre-commit
  You are about to commit to master
  Do you really want to do this? [y/n] y
```

pre-commit script

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments.  The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
# it wants to stop the commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit".

echo "You are about to commit" $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM)
echo "to" $(git branch --show-current)

while : ; do
    read -p "Do you really want to do this? [y/n] " RESPONSE < /dev/tty
    case "${RESPONSE}" in
        [Yy]* ) exit 0; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

But when i git commit and git push to the repository none of the scripts work.

```
$git commit -m "Test hooks"
[master] Test hooks  1 file
changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

My git version is `2.39.1`

I created the repository on a VM with Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS installed
Here was the procedure fro creating the repo.

```
mkdir project1.git
cd project1.git
git init --bare
```

After the creation i clone the repo to my local computer (windows).

Clone the git repository

`git clone git@{ip}:/home/git/git_repositories/project1.git/`

Comment: Does the hook script exist in your local repository, or only in the bare remote?

Comment: Only in the bare remote.

Comment: They have to exist in the local repository; client-side hooks aren't distributed with the repository.

Comment: How can i make that possible at this stage?

Comment: You have to distribute the hooks separately and ask users to put them in the right directory. Or you could use something like https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/

Comment: yeah husky is possible. But i want use the scripts in `project1.git/hooks` to make this work.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I was about to find the scripts in my local repo.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want use the scripts in `project1.git/hooks` to make this work.

A pre-commit hook for instance would not work in a bare repository (which has no working tree).
It would work only in your cloned repository, on Windows, where you can create a `myClonedRepo/.git/hook/pre-commit` script (no extension, no `.sh`), which will be run before each commit.

From the comments:

- all users could create/clone their repositories from a shared Git template repository. The article "**[Creating a Custom Git Template](https://www.darrik.dev/writing/custom-git-template/)**" gives an illustration of that approach, but means that:

  - every user must access the same shared folder
  - they need to activate the `init.templateDir` config setting in their global Git configuration
- any check which must be enforced for all the team members, especially for a distributed team, is best managed by **[server-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks)** instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Yes, it work on `myClonedRepo/.git/hook/pre-commit`. i just tested it.

Comment: @Karamokanagi Perfect, well done! On Windows, you don't need any chmod. If the hook script exist (without its .sample or any other extension), the hook will be active.

Comment: But is there a way that i can make hook scripts common to all developers local repo after clone. example the `hook/pre-commit` to check  for commenting format.

Comment: @Karamokanagi You can ask them to crreate their local repository from a common shared template (which can include hooks). See "[Creating a Custom Git Template](https://www.darrik.dev/writing/custom-git-template/)" for the general idea. But any check that needs to be enforced for a all team is better done at the server level, using a server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks).

Comment: @Karamokanagi No problem, I have edited the answer to include the conclusions from those comments.